# how to insert Date into TempTable inside Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, sql-insert, temp-tables

I have a cursor (just for practice and test cursor) and I want to Insert My Result into TempTable I tried this But I got this error

> An INTO clause is not allowed in a cursor declaration.

My code:

```
DECLARE cursor_brand CURSOR FOR
     SELECT firstname, LastName 
     INTO #tempTable_2 
     FROM Person.Person
     JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail ON SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderDetailID = Person.BusinessEntityID
     JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader ON SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
     WHERE OrderDate LIKE '%2011%' AND LineTotal > 10000
     ORDER BY LastName

OPEN cursor_brand;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_brand

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_brand
    CLOSE cursor_brand
    DEALLOCATE cursor_brand;
```

Comment: You can't use the <select ... into ... > syntax for multiple reasons. You need to fetch the columns from the cursor into variables. Then write an insert statement using those variables.

Comment: @SMor can you give me an example?

Comment: I could - but then you miss out on the learning experience that you should be trying to do by reading the documentation, searching the internet, and learning when (and WHEN NOT) to use a cursor. Hint - Inside your loop is where your insert statement goes - just a simple <insert xxx (...) values (...)>. But it is not clear why you focus on a cursor when this could be easily done in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see why you would need a cursor here. To insert into the temp table, using the `select ... into ...`  syntax is just enough, so I think your whole code should be simplified as:

```
select p.firstname, p.LastName 
into #tempTable_2
from Person.Person p
join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod on sod.SalesOrderDetailID = p.BusinessEntityID
join Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
where soh.OrderDate like '%2011%' and sod.LineTotal > 10000
```

Note that I used table aliases to shorten the query - I had to make assumptions about columns in the `select` and `where` clauses. If these assumptions are correct, then you are only selecting `person` columns, so I am actually unsure that this code does exactly what you want: if a person has more than one row that satisfies the conditions on `salesOrder` and `salesOrderDetail`, then it would be inserted more than once in the temp table. You can avoid that by using `exists` instead of `join`s:

```
select p.firstname, p.LastName 
into #tempTable_2
from Person.Person p
where exists (
    select 1 
    from Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
    join Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
    where 
        soh.OrderDate like '%2011%' 
        and sod.LineTotal > 10000
        and sod.SalesOrderDetailID = p.BusinessEntityID
)
```

Finally, if `soh.OrderDate` is of a `date`-like datatype (as it should), then you should use date functions rather than string functions to filter it. That is, replace this:

```
soh.OrderDate like '%2011%'
```

With:

```
soh.OrderDate >= '2011-01-01' and soh.OrderDate < '2012-01-01'
```